# renderbitmap access violation

Tags: c#, bitmap, uwp, access-violation

I'm currently developing a UWP app that takes a signature, and converts it to base64 for use online. Oddly it works sometimes but others it won't and gives an access violation error

The line of code is

```
await renderBitmap.RenderAsync(canvas);
```

This is placed in a dispatcher so that it can access the UI thread and has had some success but not always. The code I'm using to convert it image is:

```
await Dispatcher.RunTaskAsync(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        var renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        Debug.WriteLine("rendering bitmap");
        await renderBitmap.RenderAsync(canvas);
        Debug.WriteLine("rendered bitmap");

        var bitmap = renderBitmap;
        var img = (await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync()).ToArray();
        Debug.WriteLine("stage 1 passed - bitmap render");
        var encoded = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, encoded);
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
                      (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, 96, 96, img);
        Debug.WriteLine("stage 1 passed - created encoder");
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
        encoded.Seek(0);
        var bytes = new byte[encoded.Size];
        await encoded.AsStream().ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        retVal = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Crashed when getting signature. Error Message Below" + Environment.NewLine + e.InnerException.ToString());
    }
}
```

Was hoping someone could help me with this issue as the debugger crashes on this line.

Thanks!

Comment: I have tested your code, but I could not reproduce your issue.  Could you share a simple sample that reproduce this issue?

Comment: So that method is actually called inside a new thread like so: await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>{} - But I've also had a strange thought that maybe it's due to the fact that I'm doing this via Remote Desktop?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT - Any chance you would be able to test this on a remote desktop connection?